# Not all counsel-find-file actions are shown

Tags: ivy, counsel

Linux Mint 20.1 , Emacs 27.2, I installed Ivy, Swiper and Counsel.

So in sources file of `counsel.el` I find this:

```el
(ivy-set-actions
 'counsel-find-file
 '(("j" find-file-other-window "other window")
   ("f" find-file-other-frame "other frame")
   ("b" counsel-find-file-cd-bookmark-action "cd bookmark")
   ("x" counsel-find-file-extern "open externally")
   ("r" counsel-find-file-as-root "open as root")
   ("R" find-file-read-only "read only")
   ("l" find-file-literally "open literally")
   ("k" counsel-find-file-delete "delete")
   ("c" counsel-find-file-copy "copy file")
   ("m" counsel-find-file-move "move or rename")
   ("d" counsel-find-file-mkdir-action "mkdir")))
```

OK. Nice. Now I want to use e.g. `j` when opening a file.

So in temp folder (in Dired mode) I use command:

```
M-x counsel-find-file
```

[image]

Then select file `file2.txt`
[image]

Screen is in fullscreen mode.
And then press `M-o`. As a result the relevant actions are shown.

[image]

But why is `"j" find-file-other-window "other window"` not shown?

Comment: Have you tried to press "j"? Because here, even though it is not shown, it still is available.
Maybe it was not before I evaluated that `ivy-set-actions` form in `counsel.el` manually. But at least after I did that, "j" seems to be always available also in subsequent sessions. (So if it is really not available before loading the "ivy-set-actions" form manually, then I guess there is some weird bug in Ivy)

Comment: @dalanicolai Yes, "j" is work. When I press "j" then file open in other frame. But why this command is not visible?

Comment: It seems to me, that you encountered [this bug](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/2397) that has not yet been resolved.

When I am using a small Emacs frame, then I also don't see all actions listed, but when I switch to full screen then I see all actions (but as you already use full screen, you should probably try to resolve or find a workaround for that bug, or hope it gets resolved soon).

Comment: @dalanicolai Please report any unresolved issues in the issue you link, a new issue, or in the issue that OP submitted under https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/2881. TIA.